# Query group by 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table with 4 columns

```
id, name, key, date
 1,'A'  ,'x1','2015-11-11'
 2,'A'  ,'x1','2015-11-11'
 3,'B'  ,'x2','2015-11-11'
 4,'B'  ,'x2','2015-11-11'
 5,'A'  ,'x1','2015-11-12'
 6,'A'  ,'x1','2015-11-12'
 7,'B'  ,'x2','2015-11-12'
 8,'B'  ,'x2','2015-11-12'
 9,'D'  ,'x3','2015-11-12'
```

I want group by [key] and [date]. Result I want is:

```
2015-11-11             2

2015-11-12             1
```

`2`: date 2015-11-11 have 4 rows (1,2,3,4) but duplicate key, so when group by we only have 2 row.

`1`: date 2015-11-12 have 5 rows (5,6,7,8,9) but have 4 rows (5,6,7,8) duplicate with date 2015-11-11, I don't want calculator => we only have 1 rows (9)

I'm sorry for my english. I hope you can understand my question.

Please help me every way. I'm using mysql.

Comment: Can you explain what the `2` and `0` in the result mean?

Comment: You can see we have 4 rows. when I group by date we have 2 rows for 2 date. Date 2015-11-11 have 2 rows, but I want date 2015-11-12 have 0 row. Because date 2015-11-12 have 2 rows have [key] duplication with [key] in date 2015-11-11 => group by it is 0 row.

Comment: So jarlh has correctly answered this question?

Comment: Yes, him's answer is good. But I have question, if using sub-query is good or not good with big data? Do you have other way for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select key, date, (select count(*) from tablename t2
                   where t2.key = t1.key
                     and t2.date = t1.date
                     and not exists (select 1 from tablename t3
                                     where t3.key = t2.key
                                       and t3.date < t2.date))
from tablename t1
```

You can use a correlated sub-query to count that date's keys. Do not count if that date's key-value have already been found for an older date.

Alternative solution:

```
select t1.key, t1.date, count(*)
from tablename t1
  LEFT JOIN (select key, min(date) as date from tablename group by key) t2
    ON t2.key = t1.key and t2.date = t1.date
group by t1.key, t1.date
```

Comment: I think your way is good. My requirement only want group by [date] but not want duplicate by [key]. Do you think this way is the best? My data is very big.

Comment: What if one date has several, different key values? Can't you add some more values to your sample data, making it a bit more similar to real data - which probably is a bit more tricky than now. Don't forget to adjust wanted output too!

Comment: @ChauApple Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Strawberry I just edit my question. I'm so sorry about this.